# AIRFLOW : Customise SFTPOperator to download multiple files

Tags: python, airflow, paramiko

I'm trying to customise the SFTOperator take download multiple file from a server. I know that the original SFTPOperator only allow one file at a time.

I copied the same code from [source](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/sftp_operator.html) and I twerk by adding a new function called `get_xml_from_source()`. Please refer the code below:

```
def get_xml_from_source(sftp_client, remote_filepath, local_filepath, prev_execution_date, execution_date):
    """
    Copy from Source to local path
    """
    files_attr = sftp_client.listdir_attr(remote_filepath) # eg: /source/ HITTING ERROR HERE
    files_name = sftp_client.listdir(remote_filepath) # eg: /source/


    today_midnight = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), time.min)
    yesterday_midnight = today_midnight - timedelta(days=1)

    for file_attr, file_name in zip(files_attr, files_name):

        modified_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(file_attr.st_mtime)

        if yesterday_midnight <= modified_time < today_midnight:
        # if prev_execution_date <= modified_time < execution_date:
                try:
                    # Download to local path
                    sftp_client.get(remote_filepath, local_filepath)
                    print(file_name)
                except: # pylint: disable=bare-except
                    print("File not found")
        else:
            print("Not the file!")
```

Where this function will only download files from yesterday up to today.

I added the function at this line:

```
    with self.ssh_hook.get_conn() as ssh_client:
        sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()
        if self.operation.lower() == SFTPOperation.GET:
            local_folder = os.path.dirname(self.local_filepath)
            if self.create_intermediate_dirs:
                # Create Intermediate Directories if it doesn't exist
                try:
                    os.makedirs(local_folder)
                except OSError:
                    if not os.path.isdir(local_folder):
                        raise
            file_msg = "from {0} to {1}".format(self.remote_filepath,
                                                self.local_filepath)
            self.log.info("Starting to transfer %s", file_msg)
            # This is where it starts to copy, customization begins here
            # sftp_client.get(self.remote_filepath, self.local_filepath) <--- Original code that I commented out and replace with mine below
            get_xml_from_source(sftp_client, self.remote_filepath,
                                self.local_filepath, self.prev_execution_date, self.execution_date)
```

Note that, rest of the codes did not change. It is how it looks like in the source.

I keep hitting error at `files_attr = sftp_client.listdir_attr(remote_filepath)` with this error:

> Error while transferring from /source/ to
> /path/to/destination, error: [Errno 2] No such file.

Which obviously meant, it can't find the sftp directory. I tried running the whole function locally, it works fine.

Is there any part of the code that tied the `paramiko` connection to only get one file? I checked the `paramiko` connection for SFTPOperator, it should be just fine. In this case, how should I fix it?

This is how I established my connection when running locally :

```
def connect_to_source():
    """
    Get source credentials
    :param: None
    :return: username & password
    """
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    username, password = get_eet_credentials()
    # key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(openssh_key, password=password)
    ssh.connect(hostname=SFTP_SERVER, port=SFTP_PORT_NUMBER,
                username=username, password=password)
    client = ssh.open_sftp()

    print("Connection to source success!")
    return client
```

Lastly, below is my airflow task:

```
def copy_from_source():
"""
Copy XML file from source to local path
"""
return SFTPOperator(
            task_id="copy_from_source",
            ssh_conn_id="source_conn",
            local_filepath=f"{current_dir}/destination",
            remote_filepath= "/source/",
            prev_execution_date='{{ prev_execution_date }}',
            execution_date='{{ execution_date }}', # strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            create_intermediate_dirs=True,
            operation="get",
            dag=dag
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do something similar to you. I'm not sure what is causing the issues you are facing but this is the updated SFTP Operator I have written that gets multiple files from a server

`sftp_get_multiple_files_operator.py`

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any

from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.models import BaseOperator

from airflow.contrib.hooks import SSHHook


class SFTPGetMultipleFilesOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields = ('local_directory', 'remote_filename_pattern', 'remote_host')

    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        ssh_hook=None,
        ssh_conn_id=None,
        remote_host=None,
        local_directory=None,
        remote_filename_pattern=None,
        filetype=None,
        confirm=True,
        create_intermediate_dirs=False,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ssh_hook = ssh_hook
        self.ssh_conn_id = ssh_conn_id
        self.remote_host = remote_host
        self.local_directory = local_directory
        self.filetype = filetype
        self.remote_filename_pattern = remote_filename_pattern
        self.confirm = confirm
        self.create_intermediate_dirs = create_intermediate_dirs

    def execute(self, context: Any) -> str:
        file_msg = None
        try:
            if self.ssh_conn_id:
                if self.ssh_hook and isinstance(self.ssh_hook, SSHHook):
                    self.log.info("ssh_conn_id is ignored when ssh_hook is provided.")
                else:
                    self.log.info(
                        "ssh_hook is not provided or invalid. Trying ssh_conn_id to create SSHHook."
                    )
                    self.ssh_hook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id=self.ssh_conn_id)

            if not self.ssh_hook:
                raise AirflowException("Cannot operate without ssh_hook or ssh_conn_id.")

            if self.remote_host is not None:
                self.log.info(
                    "remote_host is provided explicitly. "
                    "It will replace the remote_host which was defined "
                    "in ssh_hook or predefined in connection of ssh_conn_id."
                )
                self.ssh_hook.remote_host = self.remote_host

            with self.ssh_hook.get_conn() as ssh_client:
                sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()
                all_files = sftp_client.listdir()

                self.log.info(f'Found {len(all_files)} files on server')
                timestamp = context['ds_nodash']
                filename_pattern = self.remote_filename_pattern + timestamp
                # fetch all CSV files for the run date that match the filename pattern
                matching_files = [f for f in all_files
                                  if f.find(filename_pattern) != -1]
                # if file type is specified filter matching files for the file type
                if self.filetype is not None:
                    matching_files = [filename for filename in matching_files
                                      if filename[-len(self.filetype):] == self.filetype]
                self.log.info(f'Found {len(matching_files)} files with name including {filename_pattern}')

                local_folder = os.path.dirname(self.local_directory)
                if self.create_intermediate_dirs:
                    Path(local_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

                for f in matching_files:
                    self.log.info(f"Starting to transfer from /{f} to {self.local_directory}/{f}")
                    sftp_client.get(f'/{f}', f'{self.local_directory}/{f}')

        except Exception as e:
            raise AirflowException(f"Error while transferring {file_msg}, error: {str(e)}")

        return self.local_directory


def _make_intermediate_dirs(sftp_client, remote_directory) -> None:
    """
    Create all the intermediate directories in a remote host

    :param sftp_client: A Paramiko SFTP client.
    :param remote_directory: Absolute Path of the directory containing the file
    :return:
    """
    if remote_directory == '/':
        sftp_client.chdir('/')
        return
    if remote_directory == '':
        return
    try:
        sftp_client.chdir(remote_directory)
    except OSError:
        dirname, basename = os.path.split(remote_directory.rstrip('/'))
        _make_intermediate_dirs(sftp_client, dirname)
        sftp_client.mkdir(basename)
        sftp_client.chdir(basename)
        return
```

`dag.py`

```
sftp_report = SFTPGetMultipleFilesOperator(
        task_id=f"sftp_reports_to_gcs",
        ssh_conn_id="sftp_connection",
        local_directory=f'/opt/airflow/dags/reports',
        remote_filename_pattern=f'reportname_',  # ds_nodash is added in the operator by accessing Airflow context
        create_intermediate_dirs=True,
        filetype='.csv'
    )
```